# MakerBot JSON-RPC Command List

Tags: makerbot, replicator+

I'm currently trying to implement a data collector on my Replicator+ by utilizing JSON-RPC. Is there an **official** reference for this? MakerBot used to host a [wiki site](http://wiki.makerbot.com/), but that seems to be gone for their "troubleshooting" pages.

Comment: have you tried via [Waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20121114075819/http://wiki.makerbot.com/) ? Or the [Documentations](https://web.archive.org/web/20121109144349/http://www.makerbot.com/docs/) ?

Comment: @Trish Thanks, that solves the mystery of what happened to the wiki. It looks like it hasn't been touched since before MB went closed-source. I think JSON-RPC was probably implemented in the 4th or 5th generation machines, maybe a little sooner?

Comment: I am not really sure how much my research does help but it's pretty much my extent of my Google-Fu

Comment: @Trish It's the same avenues I've gone down, but good info for other people that may be looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some digging, but I was able to start scripting a wrapper in C# for the RPC commands.

- [C# Wrapper](https://github.com/TrueAnalyticsSolutions/MakerBotAgentAdapterCore#api) (MTConnect Implementation)
- Unofficial [JSON-RPC Reference](https://github.com/TrueAnalyticsSolutions/MakerBotAgentAdapterCore/wiki/JSON-RPC)

I still don't understand what every method does to the machine or necessarily what the results are, so a number of the methods are marked as obsolete until I can test them.

Answer (score 1):

### The Mystery of Makerbot-Wiki

According to the Wayback machine, the wiki.makerbot.com went offline on [31st December 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20121126084944/http://wiki.makerbot.com:80/):

> Over the past three amazing years, MakerBot owners and enthusiasts around the world have shared knowledge with us and with each other. As we welcome thousands more MakerBot owners and users into the MakerBot family, we want to make sure that everyone always has the best information regarding our company and products, and that it's easily accessible.
>
> Here’s one thing we're doing to help: on December 31, as we close out the year, we will also turn off the lights at wiki.makerbot.com.
>
> The MakerBot wiki has served us well, but lately we've seen an increase in spam and a decline in community activity. Instead of continuing to maintain two separate sites, we're going to consolidate them.
>
> What that means is that, as of December 31st, the MakerBot wiki will no longer be available at this address. An archived version of the wiki as it stands today will be available at http://makerbot.com/support/archive and more former wiki content will be available at http://makerbot.com/support, which already hosts PDFs of some of the most useful Thing-O-Matic and Cupcake documentation. You may see some short periods of downtime as we finish moving this content.
>
> An archive of forum discussions will be available, but users seeking discussion with the incredibly knowledgable MakerBot community should head over to the [MakerBot Operators Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/makerbot). Requests for help and questions about MakerBot products should, as always, be sent to mailto:support@makerbot.com.
>
> Thanks for your contributions over the past few years to the MakerBot wiki. We hope you'll all continue to share your expertise with us and other MakerBot users for many years to come.

[Before that](https://web.archive.org/web/20121114075819/http://wiki.makerbot.com/), the makerbot wiki did tell that the Documentations had been moved:

> Note
>   This wiki is intended for historical MakerBot documentation and community-supported projects. The new home for MakerBot documentation is http://www.makerbot.com/docs/

---

### JSON-RPC

There is a late 2013/early 2014 [github](https://github.com/makerbot/jsonrpc) that seems to work on the JSON-RPC and which might help - and still showed [some activity](https://github.com/makerbot/jsonrpc/graphs/contributors) past the lockup of the wiki.makerbot.com. It is only very poorly documented. The earliest activity was in 2012 with the main bulk in 2013.

The JSON project predates the start of work on the [makerbot-gen5-api](https://github.com/gryphius/makerbot-gen5-api/graphs/contributors) in 2014. This might mean that it might be documented there to some degree, But it might also be present in the generation 4 API.

Comment: There is little to no documentation on the GitHub repository. I've been scouring over the code for days now trying to extract the methods. [This](https://github.com/gryphius/makerbot-gen5-api) is the closest I've come to documentation and it's not even from MakerBot.

Comment: hm, judging dates... it might be also in the late gen4 API